# What "the start of an allocated memory block" means here?

Tags: c

```
typedef struct ELEMENT
{
    int                 addr;
    int                 size;
    struct ELEMENT *    next;
} ELEMENT;

int freeMemory (ELEMENT ** freeList, ELEMENT ** allocList, int addr)
/* pre:  Parameter addr must match the start of an allocated memory block.Otherwhise return -1.
 * post: If addr is a part of allocated memory of allocList then the memory from this address
 *       with registered nrofBytes should be removed from the *allocList and added to the *freeList
 *
 *       freeMemory(freeList,allocList,addr) returns number of bytes belonging to the address addr
 *       In all other cases freeMemory(freeList,allocList,addr) returns -1.
 */
```

I am assuming that I have to check something like if(node -> addr == addr), but I am not sure if that is what they are reffering to. (It is an assignment)

Comment: You haven't even told us what the exact context of that structure is and how it is used. But at a guess, yes what you have described seems right. The `addr` parameter must match one of the `addr` values in the `allocList` elements.

Comment: Maybe now is it more clear?

Comment: A little. But yes, it does seem to be as I said (and as what I think you are saying).

Comment: is this a linked list

Comment: Btw, walking a linked list is extremely inefficient on modern hardware as the memory latency hits you on each and every dereference operation. This may be a useful teaching example, but when you need to search a list, you should not use a linked linked list. An array is always faster than a linked list, and if you can avoid searching, that's best.

Comment: Yet another tangent: Storing an address in an `int` is a bad idea. There is no guarantee that an `int` is large enough to hold an address. The bare minimum to use is `size_t`, better is `intptr_t` (that's defined to be suitable to hold a pointer), but generally you should be using `void*` for this purpose.

Comment: Well, the purpose  of this assignment is to work with linked lists, furthermore they already gave us the struct and we are not allowed to change it. Also it is for Embedded Software Design. @cmaster-reinstatemonica

Comment: I supposed as much. I did not meant to suggest that you shouldn't follow the assignment. All I wanted to point out is, that you generally don't see linked lists in well-written code *at all*. For the exact reasons I gave. Linked lists are a simple data structure, but they fail when performance is a prime concern. Which is especially true in embedded software design. The only place where linked lists are really useful is when you need to push/pop already existing objects on a stack which you never need to search.

Comment: Okok I understand your point now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to check that `addr` parameter must mactch one of the `addr` value in the `allocList` elements.